# Why is my loop not iterating over the 2nd same value in the list?

Tags: python, list, algorithm, loops, if-statement

I am creating a function to multiply the 2 largest values in the list.

For example: `nums = [5,2,5,4]`

Here my result should be 25 multiplying 5 (of index 0) with 5 (of index 2).

But it is giving 20.

Why is it not iterating or considering the next 5 in this list, i.e. 5 of index 2?

```
def max_pair_product_fast(nums):
    num1 = max(nums)
    print("Maximun = ", num1, "Index = ",nums.index(num1))
    num2 = 0
    for i in nums:
        if  nums.index(num1) != nums.index(i) and num2 < =  i :
            num2 = i
            print("Num 2 : ",num2)

    return num1 * num2

nums = [5,2,5,4]

print("Multiplication = ",max_pair_product_fast(nums))
```

Output:

```
PS D:\Code> & C:/Users/kshar/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0/python.exe d:/Code/Algo/mppf.py


Maximun =  5 Index =  0

Num 2 :  2

Num 2 :  4

Multiplication =  20
```

If I remove the condition `nums.index(num1) != nums.index(i)` then it will just multiply the maximum value (in this case 5) with itself.

Comment: `index(i)` returns the index of the _first_ occurrence of value `i`. So your approach won't work with repetitive max value,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The poster is asking what is wrong with his original code**, NOT simply asking for a block of new codes without any explanations.

This line of code is causing problem possibly

```
if  nums.index(num1) != nums.index(i) and num2 <= i:
```

Using your example, the list was [5,2,5,4]

num1 is your first maximum value, 5. This 5 has index of 0. However, your second maximum value is also 5. This 5 has index of 2.

When you write nums.index(i), you are expecting the programme to know that this second 5 is at index 2, however, **the nums.index() function will return the first occurance of a number**. Therefore, the value of nums.index(5) at this iteration will still be 0.

Hence, your programme ignores this 5, as nums.index(5) is always 0, which is equal to the index of num1.

Try this one below which avoid this problem:

```
def max_pair_product_fast(nums):
num1 = max(nums)
print("Maximun = ", num1, "Index = ",nums.index(num1))
num2 = 0
for index in range(len(nums)):
    if  nums.index(num1) != index and num2 <= nums[index]:
        num2 = nums[index]
        print("Num 2 : ",num2)

return num1 * num2
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct, but diffenent people have different approach where everyone can think differently. Your appraoach also correct also you can suggest more better way along with your answer.

Comment: @RinshanKolayil I agree, but what I meant is, many other answers are only uploading codes without any explanations. Different approaches are certainly good if they explain what went wrong originally, so that the person who asks the question gets to improve.

Answer (score 1):

```
def max_pair_product_fast(nums):
    nums.sort(reverse=True)
    return nums[0]*nums[1]
    # OR
    # nums.sort()
    # return nums[-1]*nums[-2]
    

nums = [5,2,5,4]
print("Multiplication = ",max_pair_product_fast(nums))
```

Comment: Thanks, Sir 
But I was kinda Finding Problems in My Code / approach instead of a New solution or Algo.
But Still, thank you for Providing Such a valuable approach. (I'm going to consider using this one too in next algos) 

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
def max_pair_product_fast(nums):
    num1 = max(nums)
    print("Maximun = ", num1, "Index = ",nums.index(num1))
    num2 = 0
    nums.remove(num1);
    print (nums)
    num2=max(nums)
    return num1 * num2

nums = [5,2,5,4,6,7,6]

print("Multiplication = ",max_pair_product_fast(nums))
```

Comment: Thanks, Sir But I was kinda Finding Problems in My Code / approach instead of a New solution or Algo. But Still, thank you for Providing Such a valuable approach.

Answer (score -1):

you can also do this by removing the first largest element from the list.

```
def max_pair_product_fast(nums):
num1 = max(nums)
print("Maximun = ", num1, "Index = ",nums.index(num1))
nums.remove(num1)
num2 = max(nums)
return num1 * num2
```

Comment: Thanks, Sir But I was kinda Finding Problems in My Code / approach instead of a New solution or Algo. But Still, thank you for Providing Such a valuable approach.